# Why is my null check unreachable?

Tags: android, kotlin, nullable, unreachable-code

In the following example i have an nullable property userId. I would like throw an Exception if it null. Android studio is telling me the code block inside if(userId == null) is unreachable. Can anyone explain why this is unreachable?

```
return Observable.create<Optional<UserEntity>> { it ->

        val userId: String? = firebaseAuth.currentUser?.uid

        if(userId == null){
            it.onError(throw RuntimeException("Unauthorised"))
            it.onComplete()
        }else{
            //Do something
        }

    }
```

Comment: It could be unreachable, if `firebaseAuth` isn't nullable and if `currentUser` isn't nullable and if `uid` isn't nullable? Is that right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok... I see... in fact it is the following line that contains the unreachable code:

```
it.onError(throw RuntimeException("Unauthorised"))
```

The reason: you throw your exception immediately and not when there occurs an error in processing. In fact the `onError` itself becomes unreachable.

[`onError`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Emitter.html#onError-java.lang.Throwable-) however, needs the exception to throw as passed argument, so what you rather want is something like:

```
it.onError(RuntimException("Unauthorised"))
```

i.e. omit the `throw`.

Comment: Sorry then... that was clearly not my intention ;-) But I think I did that too already... so... it happens ;-)